# Email spam/hack and odd apache logs around the same time

Tags: apache-2.2, email, spam

A friend of mine started getting failed delivery notices yesterday (June 23rd, 2014) on all of his domain e-mails, and so he asked me to look into it.

I have been looking through various logs and his account logs don't show any unusual login, however his apache logs show some interesting entries.

I did some research and based on other serverfault posts they are SSL's initial handshake. Normally I would shrug this kind of thing off as general bot activity, but given the proximity with the spam attempts I wanted to be sure:

```
...76.133.2 - - [20/Jun/2014:22:04:22 -0400] "\x80w\x01\x03\x01" 501 653 "-" "-"
...76.133.2 - - [20/Jun/2014:22:04:25 -0400] "GET /HNAP1/ HTTP/1.1" 404 887 "[removed]" "Opera/9.60 (Windows NT 5.1; U; de) Presto/2.1.1"
```

The referrer I marked as [removed] points back to the IP of his site visited.

He has 6 - 10 domains, and all of the them seem to get the same request within minutes of each other, several different times starting the 19th through yesterday (24th).

While it has stopped for now, and I told him to scan his computer(s) thoroughly, I have no idea if this is due to some vulnerability that might be indicated with those logs, or if it's a coincidence. The host is giving us so little information, about the only thing I can tell is that they didn't log into the control panel, which is not cpanel but some apparently proprietary thing. His host is IXWebhosting, if that helps.

My primary question is, could this simply be due to not having any SPF records for any of his domains? Or is this likely to be something else, or even related to those apache logs? His host notified him of the spam via a ToS violation ticket, so I'm not sure if SPF would trigger them doing that or not.

An example of one of the spam headers from the mailer daemon:

```
Return-Path: <[hidden]@wow-tek.com>
Received: (qmail 11259 invoked by uid 399); 25 Jun 2014 20:34:36 -0000
Received: from unknown (HELO wow-tek.com) ([hidden]@wow-tek.com@...29.95.247)
  by mail1201.opentransfer.com with ESMTPAM; 25 Jun 2014 20:34:36 -0000
X-Originating-IP: ...29.95.247
Message-ID: <[hidden]@wow-tek.com>
Date: Thu, 26 Jun 2014 00:34:35 +0400
Reply-To: "[hidden]" <[hidden]@wow-tek.com>
From: "[hidden]" <[hidden]@wow-tek.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
To: <[hidden]@gmail.com>
Subject: I @_m fond of rel@_xing with hot p@_ls like you.
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

(Body supressed)
```

The IP address is not his.

Also I hope I have given enough information. I really don't know a whole lot about e-mail forging or anything along those lines. I would be happy to update with more if required/requested, just let me know with what.